# Visual Studio 2010 - Target handle open by System process

Tags: windows-7-x64, visual-c++-2010

Almost every time I try to rebuild a C++ project in Visual Studio 2010 after having recently launched the build target from Visual Studio, I get this error.

> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'D:\Programming\Projects\SpecsLauncher\Release\SpecsLauncher.exe'

- I have used [ProcExp](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) from [Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals) to check and see which application still has the file open, but it comes up with the **System** process as still having it open.
- It does not appear anywhere in the Windows Task Manager, and closing and re-opening Visual Studio makes no difference.
- I can't even delete the build target from Windows Explorer.
- I do not experience this issue with anything other than executables built and run from Visual Studio.
- I thought it might be my anti-virus (Symantec Endpoint Protection), so I tried temporarily disabling it, but it made no difference.
- The only thing I can do is wait about 4 minutes and then try again.

Comment: http://www.retrocopy.com/blog/28/cant-delete-exe-files-in-vista--windows-7-solved.aspx

Comment: @HansPassant, Wow, I never in a million years would have thought the **Application Experience** service would have made that kind of difference, but I did have it disabled, and it seems to have helped so far by re-enabling it. Thanks!